# Как выставить полупрозрачность у JPanel по событию?

Tags: java, swing

Есть код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel main = new JPanel();
    main.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

    JPanel transparencyPanel = new JPanel();
    transparencyPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
    transparencyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
    transparencyPanel.setOpaque(false);

    main.add(transparencyPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JCheckBox changeTranslucency = new JCheckBox("Сделать полупрозрачность");
    changeTranslucency.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) transparencyPanel.getGraphics();
            g2d.setComposite(changeTranslucency.isSelected() ? AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.5f) :
                    AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0f));

            g2d.setColor(transparencyPanel.getBackground());
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, transparencyPanel.getWidth(), transparencyPanel.getHeight());

            transparencyPanel.repaint();
        }
    });

    main.add(changeTranslucency, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    frame.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setSize(300, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Как сделать так, чтобы по нажатию на `JCheckBox` можно было бы делать панельку полупрозрачной, а потом опять прозрачной?

Comment: Вы странное что-то делаете: сначала рисуете на панели, а потом просите свинг перерисовать ее, а панель с `opaque == false` по-умолчанию не рисуется, но зато рисуется фоновая панель. Вам лучше создать наследника `JPanel`, добавить признак прозрачности, перенести ваш код в `paintComponent`, а в обработчике на чекбоксе выставлять признак и вызывать перерисовку. И лучше использовать `ActionListener`, `ChangeListener` срабатывает на изменения модели кнопки, которые вызываются, напр, проведением мыши над кнопкой.

Comment: @zRrr что значит добавить "признак прозрачности"? Вот в этом месте я и не понимаю. Как можно добавить что-то в `paintComponent`, чтобы это что-то потом удаленно включать/выключать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то вроде этого:

```
// новый класс
class TransparentPanel extends JPanel {
    private boolean translucent = false;

    { 
        setOpaque( false ); // false означает, что панель не гарантирует
                            // что закрасит все пространство сплошным цветом
                            // swing будет предварительно отрисовывать нижележащие
                            // компоненты
    }

    public void setTranslucent( boolean value ) {
        if ( value != translucent ) {
            translucent = value;
            repaint(); // если свойство изменилось, запрашиваем перерисовку
        }
    }

    @Override
    // здесь ваш код рисования
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
        g2d.setComposite( translucent ? // выбор композита
                AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0.3f) :
                AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, 0f)
            );

        g2d.setColor( getBackground() );
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        g2d.dispose();
    }
}

public class TransparentPanelExample {
    private static void createUi() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel main = new JPanel() {
            @Override public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
                // рисуем панель в полоску, чтобы была видна прозрачность
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g.create();
                g2d.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON );
                g2d.setPaint( new LinearGradientPaint( 0f, 0f, 20f, 20f,
                        new float[] {.49f, .50f},
                        new Color[] {Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE},
                        CycleMethod.REPEAT )
                    );
                g2d.fillRect( 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight() );
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        };

        JCheckBox changeTranslucency = new JCheckBox("Сделать полупрозрачность");

        TransparentPanel transparencyPanel = new TransparentPanel();
        transparencyPanel.setBackground( Color.GREEN );
        transparencyPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
        transparencyPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

        main.add(transparencyPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        changeTranslucency.addActionListener(
                e -> transparencyPanel.setTranslucent( changeTranslucency.isSelected() )
            );

        main.add(changeTranslucency, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.add(main, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( TransparentPanelExample::createUi );
    }
}
```

Если нужна однотонная полупрозрачная заливка, можно просто переопределить `paintComponent` панели, чтобы он заливал фоновым цветом всегда, и использовать `Color` с установленной прозрачностью через `setBackground`